# Dashboard is unble to check the laptop battey state

Tags: ros, battery

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, im using turtlebot, when i run the dashboard i get this error: [WARN] [WallTime: 1342422151.301084] Unable to check laptop battery state. Exception: Value 12265 mW did not have "A" or "mA" .
I'm using asus laptop.
can u please help me out..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38848/dashboard-is-unble-to-check-the-laptop-battey-state/) by [MBN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2846/mbn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The Turtlebot dashboard displays battery info by parsing the contents of two files...

1. /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info

On my laptop, the contents of that file are... (note values may vary)

present:                 yes
design capacity:         4400 mAh
last full capacity:      4370 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          11100 mV
design capacity warning: 215 mAh
design capacity low:     150 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  65 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  4155 mAh
model number:            AS09A41
serial number:            2477
battery type:            LION
OEM info:                SONY Corp

2. /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state

present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            0 mA
remaining capacity:      4370 mAh
present voltage:         12493 mV

If either of these files do not exist, or your battery reports charge in a different way, you will run into issues (until this is fixed). You should check out this answer and see if it applies to you:

http://answers.ros.org/question/30631/turtlebot-unable-to-check-laptop-batterybat0state/

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1